# Matplotlib even frequency binned by month bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a bar chart where the `x-axis` represents months and the height of the bars are proportional to the amount of days entered into a list of dates that fall in this month. I want to dynamically update the list and the program should then update the graph as this list is extended.

I am able to create a list of dates as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

dates =  [datetime.date(2015,01,05),
          datetime.date(2015,01,18),
          datetime.date(2015,01,25),
          datetime.date(2015,02,18),
          datetime.date(2015,03,07),
          datetime.date(2015,03,27),]
```

If I run the script I would like to see something like:

[image]

Which I plotted here manually.

I know it will be possible to use a loop to run through the list of dates and manually sum the dates using if statements if the dates' months correspond etc. But I am hoping there is some more automated method in python/matplotlib.

Comment: In general it's best to also include your not-so-nice code for us as a reference. Questions with no code at all are often accumulating close votes.

Comment: Hi @cel. I understand what you said, but unfortunately I really didn't have anything to work from yet so couldn't really give a MWE. I was sure there would be some approach as given in the accepted answer that wouldn't require an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dates =  [datetime.date(2015,01,05),
          datetime.date(2015,01,18),
          datetime.date(2015,01,25),
          datetime.date(2015,02,18),
          datetime.date(2015,03,07),
          datetime.date(2015,03,27),]

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates})
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates)

df.groupby(df.dates.dt.month).count().plot(kind='bar')
```

Gives:

[image]

The `df.dates.dt.month` is getting the month for each. You could group by day, year, etc, in the same way.